# Wordpress Multisite stops old subdomains working

Tags: wordpress, wildcard, subdomain

I followed the instructions for setting up Wordpress multisite using subdomains on a Mediatemple DV server with wildcard DNS and got it working fine, however, I had previously hosted subdomains setup but now Multisite stops these from working by defaulting to the multisite 'system'. How can I set up Multisite so I can choose which subdomains it uses and which ones for it to leave alone incase I need to setup a non-wordpress solution in these ones?

Comment: Are you using the `WordPress MU Domain Mapping` plugin?

Comment: No, does that fix my problem?

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you should check it out http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ I guess the problem would be that your are using wildcard DNS for your mappings. This plugin makes it possible to specify a domain for each site.

Comment: Does this plugin not just map x.com to y.com with both sites hosted with multisite on y.com?

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood? With the plugin you can create a domain like `local.mysite.en` and then you can map this entry to one of your blogs.

Comment: I'm actually wanting to stop wordpress multisite from overriding all subdomains on the primary domain. e.g. say I wanted to setup drupal on drupal.example.com the way it works currently I can't. I want to be able to set up normal hosted subdomains and other subdomains to work with multisite.

Comment: This to me is a DNS record issue, it has nothing pertaining to WP Mu Domain Mapping. This plugin is used to host domains on multisite.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check DNS records. The way I have my instances, is I use a wildcard on a CNAME pointing to my server (@ or ip)

For subdomains that aren't apart of the "wp multisite network" I used A records pointing to the server ip. From there, those subdomains have to be parked properly. Say for instance, in WHM I create a cPanel account for subdomain.domain.com that roots to /home/subdomain/public_html - meanwhile domain.com cPanel accout roots to /home/domain/pubic_html - apache resolves both respectively.

Comment: I set up a wildcard A record *.domain.com through Plesk and set up the Apache vhost file as per the instructions, I presume the reason for all subdomains coming under the wp multisite network.

This was doing my nut in not being able to find any fix for it and coupled with the installation of a premium 'lite' theme which then broke the entire system (nothing worked at all, including subdomains) I reverted back to the single install. Seems very dangerous that one theme can screw up everything.

Comment: One thing I've noticed about premium themes is sometimes they are either 1.) outdated for 3.0 or 2.) not compatible with wp multisite. I theorize that it's intentionally not compatible with multisite.